# How can I deploy a Spring Boot application on Wildfly 10?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, deployment, wildfly

I have made a Spring Boot application that runs fine with embedded tomcat.
I'm now trying to deploy it on Wildfly 10 but I'm getting an Exception and I can't figure out what to do...

The exception :

```
2017-09-22 10:46:20,053 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 313) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/co2-device-manager-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/co2-device-manager-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT": java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.newDigester(ZZLorg/apache/tomcat/util/digester/RuleSet;Z)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/digester/Digester;
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.newDigester(ZZLorg/apache/tomcat/util/digester/RuleSet;Z)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/digester/Digester;
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldParser.<init>(TldParser.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldParser.<init>(TldParser.java:44)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.<init>(TldScanner.java:84)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.newTldScanner(JasperInitializer.java:118)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:99)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:186)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:171)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:234)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more
```

I don't understand why it mentions org.apache.tomcat since it's not even in the pom.xml anymore...

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have tried various of solutions I found on google, but none of them are working...

Comment: Just curious. Why would you like to do that? With Wildfly (or even Wildfly Swarm which is, for some aspects, equivalent to Spring Boot), you do not need Spring or even more Spring Boot as you can use Java EE specifications (CDI, JAX-RS, ...). Then, not a Spring Boot expert, but it allows to package uber jars with everything inside including Servlet Container, Web server.... So deploying a Spring Boot app to a JEE App Server seems not to have much sense?

Comment: I would like to centralize all my applications into one container. For now, I have to launch the spring boot with a command line. It's my company request, maybe there are easier way to do that but I can't...

Comment: You are encapsulating Java EE API jars in your uberjar. I 'm no Spring boot expert but there is a task to build a war file, remove all javaee jars from it and you should be good to go

Comment: Either your company is asking you for nonsense or there is a misunderstanding. You probably want to deploy your Spring app to Wildfly, for which Spring Boot is not necessary and is done quite often. If this is the case, replace Spring Boot deps and plugins in POM with plain Spring deps and you should be good to go.